# How to take in > 1 positional argument in a sequence

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my code:

```
def max_sum2(nums):
    new_sequence = []
    # first run: add up positive numbers
    for i in range(0, len(nums)):
        if i >= len(nums) - 1:
            if nums[i - 1] >= 0 and nums[i] >= 0:
                new_sequence.append(nums[i - 1] + nums[i])
            else:
                new_sequence.append(nums[i - 1])
                new_sequence.append(nums[i])
        if nums[i] >= 0 and nums[i + 1] >= 0:
            new_sequence.append(nums[i] + nums[i + 1])
        else:
            new_sequence.append(nums[i])
            new_sequence.append(nums[i + 1])
    return new_sequence
```

When I tried

`print(max_sum2(3, -10, 4, -1, 2, 3, 6, -7))`

it gave the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:/Coding/Daniel/CS2231/Test.py", line 36, in <module>
    print(max_sum2(3, -10, 4, -1, 2, 3, 6, -7))
        TypeError: max_sum2() takes 1 positional argument but 8 were given
```

May I ask how to use these sort of sequences (as in "(num, num...)") effectively, or how to take in more than 1 argument?

Note: code is unfinished, please do not highlight unfinished areas

Comment: Put them in a list?

Comment: as in try to pick out the sequence one by one and append to a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message suggests, you define a function that accepts a single argument and try to pass eight of them to it. Two simplest fixes are:

1. Call it with a single iterable as argument:

```
print(max_sum2((3, -10, 4, -1, 2, 3, 6, -7)))
```

2. Redefine the function to accept arbitrary number of arguments:

```
def max_sum2(*nums):
```

Comment: Thanks! I missed out that part and I used your method 1.

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use the '*' in python.

Ex:

```
def max_sum2(*nums):
```